# React App is firebase hosting through github actions, The apiKey of .env is not hidden

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I'm Newbie.
studying React, and I'm trying to create a project and host it on firebase, but there are the following problems.

I'm using firebase database, and I set firebase hosting to be performed when it becomes the main through github actions.

```
`const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATA_BASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_PROJECT_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};`
```

firebase.js

```
`REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY = "my api key"
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN = "my auth domain"
REACT_APP_DATA_BASE_URL = "my base url"
REACT_PROJECT_ID = "my project id"
REACT_MEASUREMENT_ID = "my measurement id"
REACT_APP_ID = "my app id"`
```

.env

```
`jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
        env:
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}'
          REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN }}'
          REACT_APP_DATA_BASE_URL: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_DATA_BASE_URL }}'
          REACT_PROJECT_ID: '${{ secrets.REACT_PROJECT_ID }}'
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PROJECT_EEEEEEE~ }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: project-eeeeeeee~`
```

hosting.yml

However, after deployment, the key appears in source > main.js. Is it supposed to be like this? I can't hide it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw9A9.png)

I want to know how to hide the API key.

Comment: It's not meant to be hidden, and you can fully hide it at all, since the data is required on the client to make the client work correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public
Thank you for the comments. I got an alarm saying it's similar to this question.
My question will be deleted soon.